# XAMPP Control Panel v3.1.0 Apache not starting?

Tags: php, xampp

As soon as I try to start Apache I get an error saying This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

Could it be an error in the php.ini?

Comment: are you by any chance using skype/have skype running on your computer?

Comment: Yes, I have Skype running on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the checkbox in Skype's advanced options that enables Skype to use ports 80 and 443. Then restart XAMPP (Apache). Apache is probably trying to start at port 80 which is already being used by Skype. Don't worry, disabling this won't affect your Skype at all.

Comment: Yup, I edited the answer. Skype will use any other port, you won't notice no difference!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm new as well and to this website and if changing the Skype port doesn't work for you or if you have another program blocking port 80, a hassle free alternative is to locate the file under xampp labeled apache>conf>httpd and search for Listen 80. 
Change the number to 8888 and save.

This worked beautifully for me but remember your website is now located at localhost://8888/...